# Parameter Interaction Graph of JFET

Tags: transistors, datasheet, jfet

I am looking at datasheet of the MMBFJ175 P-Channel JFET ([Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/J175_D-2314525.pdf)). There is one graph were I have a really hard time to understand, what it means and how to interpret it. [image].

- IDSS doesn't have a scale (I suppose it is calculated from Vds and rds?)
- Why does rds go down when increasing Vgs
- Is gfs just the reciprocal of rds?

So I guess my question is: What is this graph supposed to tell me and how do I interpret it? (Never really used JFETs much)

Comment: This graph shows how various parameters spread are related to each other.  Notice that Vgs(off) is a cut-off (turn-off) voltage. The IDSS line shows how Vgs(off) relate to Idss. For example, if you have a JFET with a Vgs(off) around 2V you should expect that the IDSS of this JFET will be at the low side of IDSS spread for a given JFET type - 3mA to 6mA IDSS spread for MMBFJ175. In short the larger the Vgs(off) the larger the IDSS will be for a given IDSS spread. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/423158/weird-fet-results-for-noob/423164#423164

Comment: The gfs is a forward transconductance \$g_{fs} = g_m = \frac{dU_D}{dV_{GS}}\$ (slope of a \$I_D = f(V_{GS})\$ ). This plot shows that the JFET with a larger Vgs(off) will have a larger transconductance as well.

Comment: @G36 I am not sure if can quite follow. Why would the Vgs(off) be spread between 2V and 10V for the same type of JFET. Shouldn’t it be somewhat similar for the same type of JFET?

Comment: Due to manufacturing process tolerances, we see a large spread in various JFET parameters among devices of the same type. Taka look here https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/J175_D-2314525.pdf page 4. For MMBFJ175 we can read that Vgs(off) can be in a range from 3V to 6V. And IDSS spreads from 7mA to 60mA. And we can do nothing about it.

Comment: @G36 would that mean that to safely turn off the JFET I should have a bias source for Vgs with >6 (e.g. 10V or so?) and could you point me to the graph where you read the 3V to 6V range?

Comment: @G36 sorry I found it. It was not on a graph but in the table on page 3 (page 4 with cover page).

Comment: The JFET is a "normally ON" device. This means that when Vgs = 0V the maximum current is flowing through it. And the name for this maximum current is IDSS. So to turn off the JFET ( or to reduce the drain current) we need to apply Vgs voltage. And if this Vgs voltage is large enough, the current will stop flowing. And the voltage that causes the transistor to stop conducting current is called Vgs(off).

Comment: @G36 Thank you for this explanation. I think the information that I was missing is that the parameter spread of JFETs is very large and that's why the datasheet has a graph for all the different Vgs(off) values and how the other parameters change in accordance.